# how can I count the occurrences > than a value for each year of a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with the values of precipitations day per day.
I would like to do a sort of resample, so instead of day per day the data is collected year per year and every year has a column that contains the number of times it rained more than a certain value.

| Date | Precipitation |
| --- | --- |
| 2000-01-01 | 1 |
| 2000-01-03 | 6 |
| 2000-01-03 | 5 |
| 2001-01-01 | 3 |
| 2001-01-02 | 1 |
| 2001-01-03 | 0 |
| 2002-01-01 | 10 |
| 2002-01-02 | 8 |
| 2002-01-03 | 12 |

what I want is to count every year how many times Precipitation > 2

| Date | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 2000 | 2 |
| 2001 | 1 |
| 2002 | 3 |

I tried using `resample()` but with no results

Comment: Can you give a minimal reproducible example and the matching expected output ?

Comment: something like `(df['precipitation'] > threshold).groupby(df['year']).sum()`

Comment: You could do: `df.precipitation.gt(2).groupby('year').count()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this bit of code:

```
# convert "Precipitation" and "date" values to proper types
df['Precipitation'] = df['Precipitation'].astype(int)
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

# find rows that have "Precipitation" > 2
df['Count']= df.apply(lambda x: x["Precipitation"] > 2, axis=1)

# group df by year and drop the "Precipitation" column
df.groupby(df['date'].dt.year).sum().drop(columns=['Precipitation'])
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tatthew you can do this with [GroupBy.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2000-01-01', '2000-01-03',
                            '2000-01-03', '2001-01-01',
                            '2001-01-02', '2001-01-03',
                            '2002-01-01', '2002-01-02',
                            '2002-01-03'],
                   'Precipitation': [1, 6, 5, 3, 1, 0,
                                     10, 8, 12]})
df = df.astype({'Date': datetime64})
df.groupby(df.Date.dt.year).apply(lambda df: df.Precipitation[df.Precipitation > 2].count())
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tatthew you can do this with [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) and [Groupby.size](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) too.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2000-01-01', '2000-01-03',
                            '2000-01-03', '2001-01-01',
                            '2001-01-02', '2001-01-03',
                            '2002-01-01', '2002-01-02',
                            '2002-01-03'],
                   'Precipitation': [1, 6, 5, 3, 1, 0,
                                     10, 8, 12]})
df = df.astype({'Date': datetime64})
above_threshold = df.query('Precipitation > 2')
above_threshold.groupby(above_threshold.Date.dt.year).size()
```